# SonarQube web-service api for rules

Tags: sonarqube

`/api/rules?language=java` is returning: *page you are looking for does not exist*.
Other apis are working fine but I want a list of rules with description for a particular profile.

How do I get that?

Answer (score 1):

The correct URL for this Web Service is: `/api/rules/search?languages=java`

For instance on Nemo: http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/rules/search?languages=java

Comment: I tried passing format parameter as &format=csv and still I am getting the response in json.

Comment: Where do you see in the Web Service API documentation that a "format" parameter is supported? => http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/rules/search Only JSON is returned, CSV is not supported.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I was referring to an older link. Can you please tell me how do I get the response as xml or csv. Right now I am writing my own java program to convert it

Comment: Well, please read again my previous comment: "Only JSON is returned"